# WordPress Sidebar Menu not working with CSS

Tags: php, wordpress, css

I'm having trouble styling the Sidebar Menu with my CSS. I just need it working with the current CSS so I can tweak it to how I need it to look. I've stated the Sidebar Menu in functions.php and created a Menu within the Admin area of WordPress, but it doesn't seem to change anything at all.

Here is the link to the page (The Sidebar Menu is where it says Our Sectors) : [View Page](http://test.snowflakesoftware.com/)

Below is the code from the sidebar.php file.

```
<div id="mod_sidebar">
    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'Sidebar' )) : ?>
    <ul>

        <li id="sidebar-nav" class="widget menu">
            <h3><?php _e('Navigation'); ?></h3>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'sidebar-menu' ) ); /* editable within the Wordpress backend */ ?>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li id="sidebar-search" class="widget">
            <h3><?php _e('Search'); ?></h3>
            <?php get_search_form(); /* outputs the default Wordpress search form */ ?>
        </li>

        <li id="sidebar-archives" class="widget">
            <h3><?php _e('Archives') ?></h3>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_get_archives( 'type=monthly' ); ?>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li id="sidebar-meta" class="widget">
            <h3><?php _e('Meta') ?></h3>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_register(); ?>
                <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                <?php wp_meta(); ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!--mod_sidebar-->
```

And below is basically the CSS for that Menu :

```
#sidebar-nav,
#sidebar-nav ul {list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; font-weight: bold;}
#sidebar-nav a {display: block; padding: 10px; width: 210px;}
#sidebar-nav li {float: left; width: 150px;}
#sidebar-nav li:hover {background-color: #5da3e3; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;}
#sidebar-nav li ul {position: absolute; width: 210px; left: -999em; background-color: #1662a7;}
#sidebar-nav li:hover ul {left: auto; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;}
```

Can anyone help me?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (but you can to use class `<div class="some_class_name">`):

```
 #mod_sidebar,
    #mod_sidebar ul {list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; font-weight: bold;}
    #mod_sidebar a {display: block; padding: 10px; width: 210px;}
    #mod_sidebar li {float: left; width: 150px;}
    #mod_sidebar li:hover {background-color: #5da3e3; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;}
    #mod_sidebar li ul {position: absolute; width: 210px; left: -999em; background-color: #1662a7;}
    #mod_sidebar li:hover ul {left: auto; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;}
```

Comment: Ok that's linking alright, so I just need to tweak the CSS as I need the Menu showing it's sub menu options...

But, now other widgets in that Sidebar are looking a bit off...

Comment: How do you get the Sidebar Menu automatically switching through different menus based on different pages? If I go to another page, I need the Sidebar Menu to change to another one...

Comment: You need to use deferent page templates. Try this solution http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages look at «Creating Your Own Page Templates»

Comment: Ok and I'm guessing I can position the Sidebar manually so when I hover over an item, it overlaps the border?

Comment: It's quite weird that the CSS isn't matching up to the current ID names. If you visit the Test version, you'll see what I mean...

Comment: You have id="menu-item-1055" and class="" Try in your css file some like this #menu-item-1055 { background: #000; } or .menu-item-1056 { background: #000; } It same things

Comment: Where it says 'menu-item-1055' that's being automatically placed somehow. I think it's via PHP or something? It's not in my CSS but then 'sidebar-nav li' is and the child elements under that including 'a' and etc

Comment: I've just cracked it! I had to rename 'Sidebar' to 'Sidebar Menu' in the functions.php to pick up the Menu from the Admin area of WordPress. Just need to style it now! Thanks for the help!